# How can I unserialize Symfony session from the file?

Tags: php, session, symfony, serialization

Symfony store session in the `app/cache/dev/sessions/sess_{session_id}` file in dev env. The file's content is something like:

```
_sf2_attributes|a:0:{}_sf2_flashes|a:0:{}_sf2_meta|a:3:{s:1:"u";i:1396424236;s:1:"c";i:1396360957;s:1:"l";s:1:"0";}bbb|i:222;IsAuthorized|b:1;
```

When I try to unserialize it with `unserialize()` function - I get `FALSE`.

How can I unserilize this?

Comment: symfony provides serialization and unserialization by itself, what if you try to get the content without unserialize it?

Comment: I try to work with this Symfony session behind framework, and I need to get `IsAuthorized` value

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just use standard PHP session mechanism. You need to set up the directory where your sessions is stored (`app/cache/dev/sessions`). And then calling standard function `session_start()` will fill the `$_SESSION` variable with all unserialized data from appropriate file.

For example you can use this code:

```
ini_set('session.save_handler', 'files');
ini_set('session.save_path', 'path/to/your/site/folder/app/cache/dev/sessions');
session_start();
```

The way described above can be used when you need to work with sessions behind Symfony framework (as OP needs). To use Symfony's session mechanism you should work with `Session` object that will provide you all the needed information:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

$session = new Session();
$session->start();

$session->all(); // will return unserialized array of parameters
```

Comment: I updated my answer to give you example. All that you need you can find here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: This is totaly wrong answer, not answering directly how to unserialize Symfony's session content and also using bad practices of Symfony.

Comment: @GrzegorzTomasiak, you are absolutely right. But OP has another problem: he didn't want to use Symfony components to work with sessions. He just needed universal way to work with sessions using Symfony and not using it.
But I updated my answer to not confuse others.

Comment: But I want to know how to unserialize the symfony session data

Comment: Is not posible, I'm creating a session handler and it get the session data already serialized

Comment: If your question is related to this question, provide more information. I didn't understand your problem. But it seems that you have another problem and so you need to ask different question.

Answer (score 0):

You can unserialize it by exploding and removing the `_something|` (and similar starting "labels") that precede the valid unserializable strings. E.g.:

```
_sf2_attributes|a:0:{}
_sf2_flashes|a:0:{}
_sf2_meta|a:3:{s:1:"u";i:1396424236;s:1:"c";i:1396360957;s:1:"l";s:1:"0";}
bbb|i:222;
IsAuthorized|b:1;
```

You can turn it into:

```
a:0:{}
a:0:{}
a:3:{s:1:"u";i:1396424236;s:1:"c";i:1396360957;s:1:"l";s:1:"0";}
i:222;
b:1;
```

And you should be able to apply unserialize() to those resulting 5 strings independently.

Answer (score 0):

Update for newest versions of Symfony.

There is option to unserialize `UsernamePasswordToken` class from serialized session data string.

```php
$exploded = explode('|', $sessionData);
$deserialized = unserialize($exploded[1]);
$securityMain = $deserialized['_security_main'];

/** @var \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken $usernamePasswordToken */
$usernamePasswordToken = unserialize($securityMain);
```