# Manually load Symfony session data from another application

Tags: php, symfony, session, serialization

I store my session data in redis - and i need to get it from another application written not even on PHP, but when i try to use default php unserialize method on stored session string that i previously fetched from redis - i get false.

Example serialized session string:

```
_sf2_attributes|a:2:{s:26:"_security.main.target_path";s:21:"http://taxi/dashboard";s:14:"_security_main";s:787:"C:74:"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken":699:{a:3:{i:0;s:60:"$2y$13$0LWym6x/aYM.TJkGlKreCO7Pc.lw5sovpbOYdJ3LMEqURiXjsKGVq";i:1;s:6:"public";i:2;s:591:"a:4:{i:0;C:22:"TaxiBundle\Entity\User":253:{a:8:{i:0;s:60:"$2y$13$0LWym6x/aYM.TJkGlKreCO7Pc.lw5sovpbOYdJ3LMEqURiXjsKGVq";i:1;s:31:"s28cx1llhk0gk8cskggk404ko0kw808";i:2;s:10:"mrandersen";i:3;s:10:"mrAndersen";i:4;b:1;i:5;i:3;i:6;s:24:"mrandersen2004@yandex.ru";i:7;s:24:"mrandersen2004@yandex.ru";}}i:1;b:1;i:2;a:2:{i:0;O:41:"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role":1:{s:47:"\x00Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role\x00role";s:16:"ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN";}i:1;O:41:"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role":1:{s:47:"\x00Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role\x00role";s:9:"ROLE_USER";}}i:3;a:0:{}}";}}";}_sf2_flashes|a:0:{}_sf2_meta|a:3:{s:1:"u";i:1485465482;s:1:"c";i:1485459877;s:1:"l";s:6:"864000";}
```

Where i can find symfony default serialize algorithm? Thx

Comment: Or just some php code which manually loads session by it's id - will work fine too!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I unserialize Symfony session from the file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22805100/how-can-i-unserialize-symfony-session-from-the-file)

Comment: Nope, there is no clue in that question. Only another way to work with sessions, but i need exactly what i asked for

Comment: you cannot use the php unserialize method with symfony sessions, symfony has its own parse method. so to do what you want, you either have to use the symfony session component to unserialize the data or dive into the session component and rewrite the unserialize function in your code

Comment: I know this) Question was - where i can see this symfony's serialize logic to copy it

Comment: I don't know where exactly the data is parsed but the session component source code can be found here : https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/5129c4cf7e294b1a5ea30d6fec6e89b75396dcd2/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session

Comment: I've searched there and searched on symfony source, nothing, i wouldn't ask...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Symfony does not have any build in session serialization algorithm, it uses php built in one which is different that regular `serialize`/`unserialize`. Check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-decode.php#108037) comment on php.net where you can find methods to manually unserialize php session data. Basically it depends on [session.serialize_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.serialize-handler) setting but algorithm you are looking for is something like this (just copied from first link I provided):

```
<?php
class Session {
    public static function unserialize($session_data) {
        $method = ini_get("session.serialize_handler");
        switch ($method) {
            case "php":
                return self::unserialize_php($session_data);
                break;
            case "php_binary":
                return self::unserialize_phpbinary($session_data);
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Unsupported session.serialize_handler: " . $method . ". Supported: php, php_binary");
        }
    }

    private static function unserialize_php($session_data) {
        $return_data = array();
        $offset = 0;
        while ($offset < strlen($session_data)) {
            if (!strstr(substr($session_data, $offset), "|")) {
                throw new Exception("invalid data, remaining: " . substr($session_data, $offset));
            }
            $pos = strpos($session_data, "|", $offset);
            $num = $pos - $offset;
            $varname = substr($session_data, $offset, $num);
            $offset += $num + 1;
            $data = unserialize(substr($session_data, $offset));
            $return_data[$varname] = $data;
            $offset += strlen(serialize($data));
        }
        return $return_data;
    }

    private static function unserialize_phpbinary($session_data) {
        $return_data = array();
        $offset = 0;
        while ($offset < strlen($session_data)) {
            $num = ord($session_data[$offset]);
            $offset += 1;
            $varname = substr($session_data, $offset, $num);
            $offset += $num;
            $data = unserialize(substr($session_data, $offset));
            $return_data[$varname] = $data;
            $offset += strlen(serialize($data));
        }
        return $return_data;
    }
}
```