# PHP Inject variable to session from CLI (Symfony Command)

Tags: php, symfony, session, variables, inject

Is there any way to inject a variable into an existing session from PHP CLI? I'm trying to do this in a Symfony command which is started asynchronously.

I've got session ID, session path, but I can't rebuild session for user.

I try read session file and unserialize it and write again to file, but i got something like:

```
Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 1316 bytes
```

Any solutions?

EDIT: found solution in
[How can I unserialize Symfony session from the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22805100/how-can-i-unserialize-symfony-session-from-the-file?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible. I had this use case, and I stored the information elsewhere to be sure to retrieve it (i.e. in a redis database).

Comment: @JulienFastré i try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22805100/how-can-i-unserialize-symfony-session-from-the-file?answertab=active#tab-top and it's help me, thanks for answer